# PHP ODBC connection to Oracle, no UTF-8

Tags: php, oracle, utf-8, odbc

I am having a problem to get UTF-8 support, when i try to connect to Oracle throught ODBC Data Source with PHP `odbc_connect()`.

Also all of this is being done under 32bits. I am using oracle XE DB for testing and instaclient11_2 32bit drivers, ODBC Data source 32it +placed on WAMP32bit server.

Althougt i have same result with Oracle 12c DB and client Home 10g 32bit drivers.

@TODAY Tested this all with 64bit instanclient drivers, added ODBC 64DataSource on 64bit WAMP Server. Still no luck to display chars corretly...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
$connect = odbc_connect("XEXDB", "username", "password");

$query = "SELECT col, 'čaļi' FROM TESST";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
  $name = odbc_result($result, 1);
  $surname = odbc_result($result, 2);
  echo "$name, $surname <br/>";
}

odbc_close($connect);

?>
```

Result i get from this code:

```
?A?IS, A?aA?i 
Gunt?rs Salts, A?aA?i
```

But should be:

```
ĶAĶIS, čaļi
Guntārs Šalts, čaļi
```

I cant find how to write `$dsn` for `odbc_connect()` to force `charset=utf-8`, so far no luck to get working $conn_string with `charset=utf-8`.

Also tried to use `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`(using this was me being desperate).

Does anyone have had similar problem, or maybe someone have some suggestions i could try?

Comment: Locks like your Oracle returns proper UTF-8 (because it shows 2 characters instead of 1) - focus on display issue. Try `echo "čaļi";` Most likely it does not work either, in this case the problem is not related to Oracle.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i already tried that, and it displays corretly, something else, u can suggest, since i am out of options. Havent mentioned all i tested, but i did a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that return of ODBC and even ADO connections to ORACLE DB had same returns of ??? instead of UNICODE chars.

To fix this, I had to add NLS_LANG string value with your DB charset in WINDOWS REGISTRY under 32 un 64 bit location for ORACLE key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE             --64 bits
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE --32 bits
```

and for STRING VALUE(REG_SZ) and VALUE in my case:

```
"NLS_LANG"="LATVIAN_LATVIA.BLT8MSWIN1257"
```

And for complete picture if someone still didn't get it, I added dump of reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE]
@=""
"NLS_LANG"="LATVIAN_LATVIA.BLT8MSWIN1257"
```